# How to uncheck CheckBox on button click in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, wpf-controls, devexpress

I have a CheckBox in GridControl Column. **After performing some operation the selected checkboxes inside GridControl must be UNCHECKED on button click in WPF**. Any idea?

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grdInfill"  Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn  AllowEditing="True">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="chkSelect"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=GlassType}"  
                        Checked="CheckEdit_Checked" 
                        Unchecked="CheckEdit_Unchecked" />
                 </DataTemplate>
             </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
         </dxg:GridColumn>
     </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
     <dxg:GridControl.View>
         <dxg:TableView Name="grdInfillInner"  ShowTotalSummary="True" AutoWidth="True" 
             DetailHeaderContent="True"  ShowIndicator="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" 
             CellValueChanging="grdInfillInner_CellValueChanging">
             <!--GroupRowTemplate="{StaticResource descriptionHeader}"-->
         </dxg:TableView>
     </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
<Button Name="BtnClearAllCheckbox" Content="Clear All Checkbox" Height="20" Width="80" />
```

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Use Data Binding. Bind checkbox with bool and on button click change the bool value that will automatically update the checkbox. Take a look at Data Bindings and INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: will you please provide sample code for above?

Comment: I don't understand the following: *`IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=GlassType}"`*. Can you please show us the VM or underlying structure?

Comment: i have changed it to: <CheckBox Name="chkSelect"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"  Checked="CheckEdit_Checked" Unchecked="CheckEdit_Unchecked"/> Sorry to say but i have copied it from else where to demonstrate checkbox in Grid. i am new to WPF. will you please help me to clear all checkbox value on button click?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: I'll try. Last question, do you want to solve it by using [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) or in code behind?

Comment: code behind please..! IsSelected is boolean field.  public bool IsSelected
        {get;set;}

Answer (score 1):

Try below.......

```
 <CheckBox Name="chkSelect"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=GlassType,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Im guessing there should be property "GlassType"

```
Public Bool GlassType {get;set;}
```

use TwoWay mode while binding and set property value GlassType as True false....

Comment: How to reset all checkbox on button click?

Comment: If your binding List<GlassType> object to checkbox then on button click you can loop List and set all as TRUE or FALSE......

Comment: it boolean value..and as it is in datatemplate cant access the control by name.. :(

Comment: Check this link     [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081725/how-to-select-all-checkbox-of-a-column-by-datagrid-header-checkbox-in-wpf-datagr)

Comment: I am using Devexpress GridControl not the DataGrid and have implemented  INotifyPropertyChanged to the current class and set the value it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

give an `Uid` to ur `checkbox`

```
<CheckBox Uid="CheckAll" />
```

than use this extension method to find the element inside the dataTemplate--->

```
public static UIElement FindUid(this DependencyObject parent, string uid)
{
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    if (count == 0) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var el = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as UIElement;
        if (el == null) continue;

        if (el.Uid == uid) return el;

        el = el.FindUid(uid);
        if (el != null) return el;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Access the CheckBox in code behind like this

```
CheckBox checkBox = myDataGrid.FindUid("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
```

Comment: sorry! error at line el = el.FindUid(uid); System.Window.UIElement doesnt contain definition for FindUid...

Comment: still same error!  i am using GridControl of Devecpress and not the DataGrid. any idea? to clear all checkxbox on button click?